# Rails after_commit callback cant save calculation to duration column in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, time

Hi I have a calculated time field called duration (integer) I am trying to save the duration calculation to my database after it is created so i can do some further calculations for example calculate meeting hours for full day. My question is how do i implement the "after_commit callback" into my code anything i have tried wont save to the database ? ..please help me

meetings.rb

```
def

duration (end_time - start_time).to_i

end
```

mettings_helper.rb

```
def duration_display(meeting)

duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.build(meeting.duration).parts format('%02d hours and %02d minutes', (duration[:hours]||0), (duration[:minutes]||0), (duration[:seconds]||0))

end
```

meetings/index.html

```
<td><%= duration_display meeting %></td>
```

database table

```
create_table "meetings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "duration"
  end
```

Comment: after_commit runs after changes have been committed to the database (transaction closed), so that's why it's not saving.. Perhaps you may wanna take a loot into before_save or before_create callbacks? If you could specify your Rails version and enrich your question with some details, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Joao im running rails 6.0.3.4 Apologise for the lack of details. I am building a small app to keep track of meeting times. I created a Scaffold table called meetings with  the columns name, start_time, end_time and duration. My app curently allows me to enter the meeting name start date and end time. I have calculated duration by convertng end time minus start time to an integer and i use a helper method above called duration display to make the integer into a readable time format example 7 hours 15 minutes. The issue is saving the duration data to the duration column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Meeting` model should look something like this:

```rb
class Meeting < ApplicationRecord
  # This will guarantee set_duration is called before saving it to the database
  before_save :set_duration

  def set_duration
    self.duration = (end_time - start_time).to_i
  end
end
```

Here you can see all [available callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) and the correct order in which Rails calls them.

You need to use `before_save` because it runs before the object is saved to the database and right after it was validated, as you can see in the link above.

Why not running `after_commit`?

The `after_commit` hook runs after the object is already saved and the database transaction has ended. It's pretty useful for many scenarios, but it's not what you are looking for at the moment.

Comment: Hi Joao no luck i am getting error "undefined method `round' for nil:NilClass" in my meetings.helper.rb file after i included the above code. The meetings helper method is used to take the integer value duration and alow me to convert it to real time example 7 hour 10 minutes     def duration_display(meeting)
        duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.build(meeting.duration).parts 
 format('%02d hours and %02d minutes', (duration[:hours]||0), (duration[:minutes]||0), (duration[:seconds]||0))
 end
i can see that the duration still isnt saving to the database am i missing something else

Comment: Is it a public repository? Do you mind if I take a look at it?

Comment: yes let me clean it up a bit and send you the github link

Comment: @SarahDuffy I'm really sorry. It was missing a `self.` before the duration. I editted my answer to reflect this. `def set_duration self.duration = (end_time - start_time).to_i end`

Comment: That worked Joao thanks a million for your help reall appreciate it